# The argument type 'MaterialColor?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'

Tags: flutter

The argument type `MaterialColor?` can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'.

How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet?

Comment: what is code snippet? sorry newbie dude

Comment: You need to paste code instead of code image, so that others can test and provide better answer.  You can check about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

it's MaterialColor Type so you should change

> Colors.green

to

```
 MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                            return Colors.green; 
                          ),
```

same to Colors.red